# General method for making sub arrays around a particular element

Tags: matlab, arrays

What is a quick, elegant way of using MatLab to form a subarray around a particular element? Element are selected randomly from the data, so you can't take a subarray in the normal way (it has to be generalized for the elements that are selected). What I mean is, forming an array for example 5x5 or 7x7 or something, where the middle element is the one you want.

---

Thanks, but I mean a more general approach. Sorry for not being clear. What I mean is something like, let's say

```
a = magic(10)          
b = find(a<8) %giving linear indices     
m = size(a)      
[r,c] = ind2sub(m,b) %giving rows and columns of the elements that you later want to select
```

and then I thought about doing the rest using for loops but am not really sure how to generalize it and wondered, like I said, if there's an easier way to do it using MatLab.

The reason for such a general approach is I want to analyze any array for elements with certain properties and then be able to form a subarray around each element to basically zoom in on it for further data analysis if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some examples of how you can approach this problem:

```
mat = rand(10);  %# A 10-by-10 array of random elements

vec = -3:3;      %# To make a 7-by-7 subarray
subArray = mat(5+vec,4+vec);  %# Get subarray centered on element (5,4)

vec = -2:2;      %# To make a 5-by-5 subarray
subArray = mat(3+vec,3+vec);  %# Get subarray centered on element (3,3)
```

Of course, you'll have to be wary of conditions where your subscripts extend beyond the bounds of the matrix you are indexing, and then decide how you want to deal with such a situation (i.e. only return the part of the subarray that is within the larger matrix, or pad the edges of the larger matrix using [PADARRAY](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/padarray.html) to avoid such a situation, etc.).

**EDIT:**

To generalize the above for sets of points that you want to get subarrays around, [the solutions given by Jonas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678857/general-method-for-making-sub-arrays-around-a-particular-element/2679797#2679797) should work well. The only drawback is that you would need to have access to the [Image Processing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/image/). Here's a solution that will work without additional toolboxes, using `a`, `r`, and `c` as you have defined them in the question:

```
blockSize = 3;                             %# Block size around each point
padSize = floor(blockSize/2);              %# Padding size for the matrix
aPad = padarray(a,[padSize padSize],NaN);  %# Pad the matrix with NaNs
rPad = r+padSize;                          %# Shift the row indices
cPad = c+padSize;                          %# Shift the column indices
blockIndices = (1:blockSize)-ceil(blockSize/2);  %# Create indices for a block
getBlockFcn = @(r,c) aPad(r+blockIndices,c+blockIndices);  %# Function to get
                                                           %#   a block
subArrays = arrayfun(getBlockFcn,rPad,cPad,...  %# Create a cell array with
                     'UniformOutput',false);    %#   one block per cell
```

This will give you an N-by-1 cell array `subArrays`, where N is the number of points you have. If, for example, you want to get the maximum value of the subarray for point 3, you can do the following:

```
maxValue = max(subArrays{3}(:));  %# MAX will ignore NaN values
```

To take a mean of the entire subarray, you either have to remove [NaN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/nan.html) values first (using the function [ISNAN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/isnan.html)), or use the function [NANMEAN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/stats/nanmean.html) from the [Statistics Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/stats/):

```
mat = subArray{3}(:);                %# Values from subarray
meanValue = mean(mat(~isnan(mat)));  %# Mean of non-NaN values
%# Or...
meanValue = nanmean(subArrays{3}(:));  %# Mean of non-NaN values
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to gather the individual (possibly overlapping) neighborhoods into an array so that you can process each neighborhood individually, you can use [IM2COL](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/im2col.html). If you want to create a 'halo' around each element to easily capture all candidate regions, so that overlaps are not counted twice, you can use [IMDILATE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/imdilate.html).

**Example for im2col**

```
%# create array and get linear index of interesting elements
a = magic(10);
b = find(a<8);

%# define region size
subSz = 3; %# for 3x3 array
halfSz = floor(subSz/2); %# for a 3x3 array, there window extends 1 pix to each side

%# pad a with NaNs so that sub-window never goes outside the image
ap = padarray(a,[halfSz halfSz],NaN);

%# convert ap to columns - there are 9 rows (for 3x3 window) and as many columns as there
%# are elements in a (100 in this example)
apCol = im2col(ap,[subSz,subSz]);

%# select columns of interest
%# the first column contains the first neighborhood of interest, the second column 
%# the second neighborhood etc.
interestingColumns = apCol(:,b);

%# take e.g. the average of each neighborhood
avg = nanmean(interestingColumns,1);
```

**Example for imdilate**

```
%# create array and get logical mask where 1 indicates an interesting element
a = magic(10);
bw = (a<8);

%# define region size
subSz = 3; %# for 3x3 array

%# grow each element, so that a single 'good' pixel is in the center of a 3x3 mask
bwDil = imdilate(bw,strel('square',subSz));

%# show the centers in white, 'halo' in grey
%# note the overlaps
figure,imshow(bw+bwDil,[])

%# take the average of all 'labeled' pixels
avg = mean(a(bwDil));
```

Comment: +1: Nice solutions. The only limitation is the need for the Image Processing Toolbox to use the functions IM2COL and IMDILATE.

Comment: With respect to the first solution, I think you forgot to adjust the indices `b` to take into account the padding added to the matrix.

Comment: I think not. im2col with the default sliding window gives (nRowArray-nRowWindow+1)*(nColArray-nColWindow+1) columns. If you pad with half the window size rounded down, you get exactly nRowArray*nColArray sub-windows. Thus, you index directly with b.

Comment: You're right. I mistakenly thought that the default block type used by IM2COL was 'distinct', when it's actually 'sliding'.